# Менять фон body?

Tags: vue.js

Есть задача при вводе кода цвета менять фон body.

```js
var app=new Vue ({
el: '#app',
data: {
  color=""
},
methods: {
  colorBg: function () {
    document.body.style.backgrondColor = color;
  }
}


})
```

```html
<div id="app">
 <input type="text" v-model="colorbg">
 <button @click="colorBg">Change color!</button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

Comment: У вас банальные синтаксические ошибки  и опечатки, начиная от `backgrondColor` и `color=""`

Comment: color: "" сделал что не так в первом варианту ?

Comment: `document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.color;`

Comment: `v-model="color"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const vm = new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    colorBg: '#ffffff'
  },
  watch: {    // отслеживание свойства автоматически реагирует на любое его изменение
    colorBg(newValue) {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = newValue;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input type="color" v-model="colorBg">
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```